# UITextView Typing Animation

Tags: ios, swift, timer, uitextview

I have a `uitextview` with a fixed width and height.

To make the text more digestible, I wanted to perform a character-by-character typing "animation", and was able to get it to work using a `Timer` object.

My only issue is...when the 1st character is typed for a word that will spill over to the next line, instead of typing that 1st character on the next line, it types on the current line. When the typing hits the end of the `uitextview`, it's only then that all the previously typed characters of the word are brought over to the next line.

This results in a jerky typing animation, and I'm wondering if it's at all possible to make it smoother by typing the first character on a new line ahead of time. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my current function:

```
func type(text: String) {

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.alignment = .center
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 10

    let bodyAttributes = [
        NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
        NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    ]

    let characters = Array(text)
    var characterIndex = 0

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        guard let self = self else { return }

        while characters[characterIndex] == " " {
            attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: " ", attributes: bodyAttributes))
            textView.attributedText = attributedString

            characterIndex += 1

            if characterIndex == characters.count {
                timer.invalidate()
                return
            }
        }

        let char = String(characters[characterIndex])
       
            attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: char, attributes: bodyAttributes))
        
        textView.attributedText = attributedString

        characterIndex += 1

        if characterIndex == characters.count {
            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

Re: Naveet's answer, result:
[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

discovered a [repo](https://github.com/rimh/RimhTypingLetters/tree/master) that creates a custom `uitextview`

Answer (score -2):

```
func type(text: String, into textView: UITextView) {
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 10

let bodyAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .foregroundColor: UIColor.black,
    .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
    .font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
]

var characterIndex = 0
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textView.attributedText ?? NSAttributedString())

Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true) { timer in
    guard characterIndex < text.count else {
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }
    
    let currentCharacter = text[text.index(text.startIndex, offsetBy: characterIndex)]
    let characterString = String(currentCharacter)
    
    attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: characterString, attributes: bodyAttributes))
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
    
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: attributedString.length)
    let boundingRect = attributedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: textView.frame.width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading], context: nil)
    
    if boundingRect.height > textView.bounds.height {
        // If the text has overflowed to the next line, move to the next line
        attributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: "\n", attributes: bodyAttributes))
        textView.attributedText = attributedString
    }
    
    characterIndex += 1
  }
}
```

I have updated the code as per requirement please check and let me know if it works. uploading video

Re -

[image]

Comment: appreciate the answer. i tried integrating but seeing some weird behavior where characters of words are split across 2 lines...updated post with a test screenshot for reference!

Comment: Hey thanks! let me check it

Comment: Check video as well @Chris https: // we. tl / t - 0wY5CW63KG combine this url by removing spaces

Comment: I tested the updated code and am still seeing the same issue, as well as some weird new line behavior as I've updated the image in my post. also, the image you provided mirrors my issue where, for example, "Your" is split across the first and second line as "You" and "r". "text" is "tex" and "t". "here" is "he" and "re".

Comment: Here is an update you can update -> paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
 in my case it is not breaking the words now. adding the updated image in my answer

Comment: thanks for the update. i tried the latest function you posted and still run into the same issue.